# I don't exactly understand how am I going to predict custom data with keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, neural-network

**Example Code**

```
import os
import random
import time
import numpy as np

# first neural network with keras make predictions
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

def network():

# load the dataset
    dataset = loadtxt('blackjackdata.txt', delimiter=',')
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = dataset[:,0:4]
    print(X)
    y = dataset[:,4]
    print(y)
# define the keras model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
# make class predictions with the model
    predictions = model.predict(X) 
# summarize the first 5 cases
    for i in range(20):
        print('%s => %d (expected %d)' % (X[i].tolist(), predictions[i], y[i]))
```

**My train data four input and one output (input,input,input,input,output)**

```
2,10,2,8,1
10,20,10,10,0
5,15,7,8,0
2,10,2,8,1
10,20,10,10,0
5,15,7,8,0
2,10,2,8,1
10,20,10,10,0
5,15,7,8,0
2,10,2,8,1
10,20,10,10,0
5,15,7,8,0
2,10,2,8,1
10,20,10,10,0
5,15,7,8,0
2,10,2,8,1
10,20,10,10,0
5,15,7,8,0
2,10,2,8,1
10,20,10,10,0
5,15,7,8,0
5,13,3,10,1
```

My problem is I want to add custom input data and I want to see what will be predict but I am getting error about array shape I changed array shape but I don't understand what am I going to do exactly.

```
predictions = model.predict(X) <--- I want to change here with a custom input like and get output
predictions = model.predict([7,15,10,5])
```

> Error:ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected shape for your input with one sample is `(1, 4)`, so you should reshape your data appropriately:

```
predictions = model.predict(np.array([7,15,10,5]).reshape(1, 4))
```

You can also get the same effect with:

```
predictions = model.predict(np.array([[7,15,10,5]]))
```

As `np.array([[7,15,10,5]]).shape` is `(1, 4)`

Comment: Matias always at the right time and place, nice answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Try reshaping your input like this:

```
predictions = model.predict(np.array([7,15,10,5]).reshape(4,-1))
```